# In Oracle SQL, how to retrieve the first, second words, From a group of words using regular expressions

Tags: oracle

Using regular expression i would like retrieve the second word and the first letter of the second word from a group of words I was able to retrieve the first word,and the first letter of the first word, i would like to do it for the second one.

```
Select regexp_substr('Red blue Green', '[A-z]*') "First word",  regexp_substr ( 'Red blue Green', '[A-Z]' ) "the first letter of first Word" FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table table_x(
str VARCHAR2(500)
);

INSERT into table_x (str) VALUES ('red blue green');

INSERT into table_x (str) VALUES ('one two three four');
```

Here is a generic solution with bind variables.

```
WITH  got_wordn  AS
(
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ( str
                , '\S+'
                , 1
                , &word_num
                ) AS wordn
    FROM    table_x
)
SELECT  wordn
,    SUBSTR (wordn, &char_num, 1)    AS charx
FROM    got_wordn
;
```

This solution I hardcoded the VALUES you were looking for. 1st character in second word.

```
WITH  got_wordn  AS
(
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ( str
                , '\S+'
                , 1
                , 2
                ) AS wordn
    FROM    table_x
)
SELECT  wordn
,    SUBSTR (wordn, 1, 1)    AS charx
FROM    got_wordn
```